# Notice: Undefined variable: page in F:\wamp\www

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I need a really help since I could not find the problem in my coding. I have an included pagination.php file in cutomer.php file. The follwoing "Notice: Undefined variable: page in F:\wamp\www..." notice is continuously popping up in every single page where I have included. Please help me. Thank you!

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

$stages = 3;

if(isset($_GET['page']))

$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);


if($page){                                 **//line 57**
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
}else{
    $start = 0; 
    }   

// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

// Initial page num setup
if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}                **//line 68**
$prev = $page - 1;  
$next = $page + 1;
```

---

> Notice: Undefined variable: page in F:\wamp\www\homepage\includes\pagination.php on line 57
>   Notice: Undefined variable: page in F:\wamp\www\homepage\includes\pagination.php on line 68

Comment: It might be duplicate however that post did not give me a solution. Because I needed more specific and simple solution to my problem

Comment: Read more carefully. That's also mentioned over there. (And in many of the hundreds other duplicates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize `$page` before the if isset statement and the error should go away

It is because if the if statement returns false, `$page` would be an undefined variable. The notice means that that the variable should be defined no matter what path the code takes.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It is the correct answer.

Comment: Do I have to change everywhere where $page is mentioned? Because if I correct one the other is popping up. Is there any way that I can do in a simple way?

Comment: you could initialize `$page = NULL` or something to that effect before the line `if(isset($_GET['page']))` and all notice's should go away.

Comment: That's the technique that I wanted to get :). Ahmed, is it safe way to do that. It seems it really solved my problem.

Comment: Yes It is safe and actually good practice to initialize variables to NULL or something of that sort before in cases where variables are assigned values in an if condition with no else.

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple and good technique!

Answer (score 5):

When your variable `$_GET['page']` is empty, `$page` won't be defined.

To avoid this, you might change

```
if($page) {
```

to

```
if (isset($page)) {
```

...or something with a similar effect.

Better would be to initialize `$page` before using it, but that would perhaps require to change some of the logic afterwards.